# Broken maven dependency while closing the project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am facing an issue with maven.

I created a project A, build it and did maven install. I see the jar file copied in local repo.

I included the project A's POM dependency in Project B. Project B is now able to reference the project A. The concern here is in eclipse when I expand Maven dependencies in Project explorer it shows me reference to project A instead of jar.

Now when I close project A in workspace of eclipse, the project B could not reference the project A.

Could you please help me understanding and fixing this issue.

Regards,

Amandeep

Comment: Try telling maven to recalculate dependencies for project B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The M2E plugin in Eclipse is able to *see* whether a workspace project already satisfies a dependency in another project. You observed it already. If the project is not in the workspace, the dependency will be served by the local and/or the remote repository.

If you close a dependency project, you first have to make a *Maven Update*. Simply rightclick your project, select "Maven", then "Update". This will recalculate the project settings and its dependencies.